# Prove that the Principal Ideal $(6+\sqrt{-13})$ of $ R = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \sqrt{-13}$ is the square of a prime ideal $P$ of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I want to prove that the Principal Ideal $(6+\sqrt{-13})$ of $ R =  \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \sqrt{-13}$ is the square of a prime ideal $P$ of $R$

So far I was able to show that 7 is split in R and I believe that the $(7) = (7, \sqrt{-13} -1)(7, \sqrt{-13} +1)$. (Note: $N(6+\sqrt{-13}) = 14$ so by unique prime factorization must equal the product of two prime ideals of norm $7$ which must be unique because 7 is split).

Where I am stuck is showing that $(7, \sqrt{-13} -1)^{2} = (6+\sqrt{-13})$ or  $(7, \sqrt{-13} +1)^{2} = (6+\sqrt{-13})$

Also, any suggestions resources, or tricks on how to simplify ideals would be appreciated.

Also, R is the ring of integers.

Comment: You usually show that two ideals are equal by showing that either has a generating set contained in the other. So what's stopping you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it:
\begin{align}
(7,1-\sqrt{-13})^2&=\bigl(49,7-7\sqrt{-13},\,(1-\sqrt{-13}\,)^2\bigr)\\
&=\bigl(49,\,(6+\sqrt{-13}\,)(1+\sqrt{-13}\,),\,2(6+\sqrt{-13}\,)\bigr)\\
&=(6+\sqrt{-13}\,)\bigl(6-\sqrt{-13},\,1+\sqrt{-13},\,2\bigr)\,,
\end{align}
at which point all that remains is to show that $(6-\sqrt{-13},\,1+\sqrt{-13},\,2)$ is the unit ideal, but that’s clear.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful! I didn't think to set $49 = (6+\sqrt{-13})+(6-\sqrt{-13})$ then you get that result by factoring that's cool. Could you also just get ride of the 49 because you know that the norm of an ideal is in the ideal? $49 \in (6+\sqrt{-13})$ because the norm of $(6+\sqrt{-13}) = 49$?

Comment: What you say is right. I like this very primitive method, because it gives equality at every stage.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the norm of $I = (6 + \sqrt{-13})$, as you intended. Note that $N(I) = 6^2 + 13 = 49$. On the other side $7$ splits in $R$, i.e $(7) = \mathfrak p_1 \mathfrak p_2$, where $\mathfrak p_1 = (7,\sqrt{-13}+1)$ and $\mathfrak p_2 = (7,\sqrt{-13}-1)$ and these are the only prime ideals of $R$ having norm $7$. Thus we must have that

$$I = \mathfrak p_1^2 \quad \quad \text{or} \quad \quad I = \mathfrak p_2^2 \quad \quad \text{or} \quad \quad I = \mathfrak p_1 \mathfrak p_2$$

Note that the last option isn't possible, as $I \not = (7)$. Hence $I$ is a square of prime.

Furthermore, you can explicitly compute that $I \not = \mathfrak p_1^2$. Indeed if that is the case then we have that $\mathfrak p_1 \mid I \implies I \subset \mathfrak p_1$. But then

$$1 = 3\cdot(6 + \sqrt{-13}) - 3\cdot (1+\sqrt{-13})  - 2 \cdot 7\in \mathfrak p_1$$

A contradiction.

Comment: I like this method, too.

Comment: This is clever and helpful to see